# How to stop quitting vim but close windows?

Tags: key-bindings

For me it's very annoying to have two functions to close window (`:quit`) or quit vim. I just want one command to close window and another command to quit vim. For example `:q` command to close window and `:e` to quit/exit vim. How to create these shortcuts in vim configuration?

Comment: In what practical case would you want to close all windows without leaving Vim?

Comment: No, but it can be a third command to close all windows without quitting vim

Comment: Maybe you want `:bd`?

Comment: @megas That is not what I asked, I try to understand what use you can have of closing all windows without closing Vim.

Comment: @nobe4 Ok, I think it's more convenient to have two separated commands to close and to exit then just one command but it's behaviour depends on how many window I have opened. In my vim experience i have exited vim many times but I didn't want to.

Comment: I think if you don't have anything to display, keeping Vim open is useless. (also, it's not for the few seconds it takes to launch that closing and opening it again is blocking)

Comment: Vim always has *at least* one tab page, one window and one buffer. Closing all buffers is exactly the same thing as closing Vim.

Comment: Like the other commenters, I'm slightly unclear on what state you're attempting to achieve. After you have closed all the windows, what do you expect to see in your terminal? A new, empty buffer? The Vim start-up page? A giant window-sized statusline? Or are you expecting some new sort of "no window here" background? (Which, to be clear, is not something that exists in the current codebase.) Or are you just looking for the `:qall` command: to close Vim without manually closing each window one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I very much dislike having to type out the entire word "close" - its smallest abbreviation is still `:clo`.

To solve this, I created the following command in my vimrc:

`command -nargs=0 C :close`

This means I have a nice, quick command `:C` which is very similar to `:q` but it only closes the current window, rather than quits. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 7):

If it's windows you're after, use `:close` or `ctrl-w c` to close windows one by one (except the last one - it won't let you do it).

You also have `:only` to keep just the current window and close all others (or `ctrl-w o`).

The buffers, that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want one command to close window

- `:quit`, or `:quit!` to abandon changes.

> and another command to quit vim.

- `:qa`, or `:qa!` to abandon ALL changes.